# Перенос базы данных с одного сервера MySQL на другой

Tags: mysql

Переношу БД (MySQL).
Перенос делаю самым обычным методом - "copy-past" каталога в каталог "data".
Далее стартую и смотрю, таблицы в БД выдают "Rows -1". Смотрю через Navicat.
Не первый раз переношу БД, но тут что-то не то. ПО не моё и БД создавал не я.
Может что-то с доступом?
Просто не знаю, как выглядят запароленные БД из Navicat.
Пароль при установке MySQL на root ставил естественно свой.
Export-Import в этом существенно поможет?
P.S. Если БД под доступом, то это всё? Туши свет?
БД обширная, набивалась несколько лет. Организация теперь решила писать свое ПО, так как содержание текущего стало проблематично.
Неужели БД насмерть привязана к разработчикам, а не к предприятию (это же уже авторские права)?
Или проще надавить (по закону) на разработчиков, то-бы они выдали пароль на доступ к БД?
P.P.S (!)
Немного становится понятнее. В файлах базы нет файлов MYI и MID! Это как-то хитро БД делали, что они могут лежать в других каталогах?
(Сегодня доступа к тому ПК не имею, посмотреть смогу лишь завтра)
Почему так?

---

UPD:
Проблема решена!
Угон пароля на root. (жадный установщик (продавший ПО организации), установил какую-то, мне неизвестную, тулзу по управлению БД, а пароль в ней был просто сохранен в закрытом виде. Ведь такие разработчики всё время думают, что покупатель ЛОХ, но покупатель через несколько лет нанимает другого разработчика, и та контора остаётся без денег за, якобы "поддержку и сопровождение", а это обновление списка фамилий участников комиссии в собственной БД(!!!) или обновление 5-10 вопросов из тестовых задач. Плюс, ко всему, такие разработчики получают ещё большой толстый минус и очернение в  репутацию по всему городу!)
P.S. Ребята, ПО надо продавать честно!
БД созданная покупателем ПО, является 100% собственностью организации купившей данное ПО. И имеет полное право на предоставление пароля к БД.

Comment: Возможно таблицы в innodb (данные лежат в файлах ibdata, которые не в директории data). Пользуйтесь mysqldump

Comment: @tutankhamun Очень на то похоже.

Answer (score 2):

Перенос данных копированием каталога данных в случае MySQL возможно только если в базах данных используется исключительно тип таблиц MyISAM (разумеется операция осуществляется после остановки сервера - иначе данные будут повреждены). В случае MyISAM и мета-информация, и индексы и данные полностью располагаются в каталогах баз данных. Если имеются таблицы InnoDB - данные могут находится в едином табличном пространстве.

Перенос данных через копирование применяют очень редко. Только если у вас MyISAM-таблицы, и, как правило, через утилиту `mysqlhotcopy`, входящую в состав MySQL.

Штатным переносом данных из одной базы данных в другую является процедура создания и разворачивания SQL-дампа: текстового файла с SQL-инструкциями, воспроизводящими базу данных. Создать дамп dbname.sql базы данных `dbname` можно при помощи утилиты `mysqldump`

```
mysqldump -u user -p dbname > dbname.sql
```

развернуть его на новом сервере в заранее созданной базе данных `dbname_new` можно при помощи утилиты `mysql`

```
mysql -u user -p dbname_new < dbname.sql
```

Вместо `user` - указывается имя MySQL-пользователя, из под которого осуществляются операции, параметр `-p` сообщает, позволяет ввести пароль сразу после запуска команд. Утилиты входят в состав любой инсталляции MySQL и доступны из командной строки.

Comment: На счёт дампов БД, я их делаю через Navicat (время от времени).
Вопрос состоит не в том, как сделать дамп и развернуть его.
Берите немного выше.  Т.е. если я не знаю пароля от root на ПК с БД, смогу ли я приконнектиться менеджером MySQL к БД для создания дампа? Ведь вряд ли. Или всё же есть возможность?

Comment: @I_CaR Тогда еще проще, сделайте дамп через Navicat или возьмите уже готовый и разверните его на новом сервере.

Comment: Я немного комментарий выше дополнил.

Comment: @I_CaR Если есть права на перезапуск сервера MySQL, то можно перезапустить его без прав доступа. Для этого в конфигурационный файл my.cnf/my.ini следует добавить директиву skip-grant-tables - можно будет зайти из под любого пользователя в том числе root без пароля и выполнить любые операции: снятие дампа, назначение нового пароля и т.п.

Comment: @chops - спасибо большое, за проф.ответ! Завтра доберусь до того места и ковырну базу как следует, вместе с корнями.

Comment: @chops, принёс БД второй раз (выгрузить Navicat не дал, так как нет доступа к БД по юзеру - так вот продают ПО в г. Красноярске ВУЗы), но в ней таки нет MYD и MYI файлов. (перерыл весь ПК). Возможно ли такое? И ещё одно заметил, есть какие-то "пухлые" файлы без расширения, но с данными (см.в HEX) с названием: "ib_logfile0". Бывают ли MySQL БД без файлов MYD и MYI?

Comment: @I_CaR, да бывают, скорее всего дело имеете в InnoDB - в ней нет файлов MYD и MYI - данные и индексы хранятся в едином многотабличном пространстве.

Comment: @chops, спасибо за внимание к проблеме, но разобрался. Действительно, предыдущие разработчики, продавшие ПО установили пароль на БД. Их человек нечаянно показал, тулзу в которой я и узрел скрытый пасс. Ну а дальше, дело техники, т.е. Delphi-программирование ещё рулит!